# Getting invalid json response while using fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I'm fetching the Clash of Clans API, but when I try to `api.json()` it, there is an Fetch-error.

FetchError: invalid json response body at https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/players/#9JYPUVU2J reason: Unexpected end of JSON input.

code:

```
clashofclansApi = await fetch(`https://api.clashofclans.com/v1/players/#${encodeURIComponent(tag)}`, {
    method: `GET`,
    headers: ({
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${API_TOKEN}`,
    })
})
api = await clashofclansApi.json()
```

Comment: What is the JSON data? Did you try to check it with https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Your link is broken why do you want to .json() it?

Answer (score -2):

nvm changed the # to %23, but thanks to everyone

Comment: For the sake of people that may stumble on your question, what did you replace with `%23` ?

Comment: the # in the tag